# iOS changing outlets -- Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I created labels and textfields, but I named them to something that was wrong. 
Because I use Android I did tv_xxx <-- textview, and not tf_xxxx <--textfield...

So, what I did was I deleted the IBOutlets from the header file and the .m file.
I also deleted them from the designer.cs file.

The designer.cs file, however, does not like this because it still thinks they are still existant.

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tv_xxxx
```

When I temporarily put the :

```
[Outlet]MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField tf_xxx { get; set; }
```

It works... But is there anyway I can make it so it doesn't look for this anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode, right click on your controller or view where the old outlets were.

A black popup should appear with all your outlets. You should see the old ones in the popup with warning exclamation points--delete them.

The `key value coding-compliant` error means you have an outlet defined in a XIB or Storyboard, but not on the class.